# Как перевести строку в std::chrono::system_clock::time_poin в c++?

Tags: c++, время, std-chrono

Мне необходимо перевести строку формата `"2021-06-04T12:40:01.194Z"` в тип `std::chrono::system_clock::time_poin`.  Как сделать это в плюсах.
В си есть метод для выполнения подобной задачи

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213326/how-to-convert-a-string-variable-containing-time-to-time-t-type-in-c

Но мне нужен с++ стиль.

Comment: так там ответе уже есть, или хочется чего то магического?

Comment: Я понимаю, что с++ типы для работы со временем это обертка над си типами, но не понимаю как получающийся в том примере тип time_t перевести в нужный мне тип @KoVadim

Comment: посмотрите на это https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/from_time_t

Comment: @KoVadim, а есть способ обрабатывать еще и миллисекунды?

Comment: в промежуточной структуре похоже нет https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime